# Bingo Card Game in Java

Tags: java

I created two methods for my Bingo Game in Java. One method creates a new board which populates the Bingo Board with integers according to the Bingo rule (1-75). My second method generates random numbers with a range of 1 - 75.

```
public static int drawNum(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(75)+1;
    return num;
}

public static void bingoCard(){


    int [][]card=new int [5][5];
    ArrayList<Integer> alreadyUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean valid = false;
    int tmp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        for(int row = 0; row < card.length; row++){
            while(!valid){
                tmp = (int)(Math.random() * 15) + 1 + 15 * i;
                if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                    valid = true;
                    alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
                }
            }
            card[row][i] = tmp;
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    card[2][2] = 0;

    //create array to make title.  
    String title []={"B","I","N","G","O"};

    for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
        System.out.print(title[i]+ "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();

    for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<card[row].length;col++){
            System.out.print(card[row][col]+ "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

What I need help with is, how do I check whether or not the drawNum() method corresponds to any values stored inside my bingoCard() array? If so, print out a new array with the integers filled in. If the condition is met for a bingo, then you win.

I hope I don't make it sound like I want you to do it for me, but I am confused as to how to start coding that part. Thank you.

Comment: Where's this getNum() method and where's it being called?

Comment: You should really learn object oriented programming. It will make your life a lot easier. Separating code into logical sections (methods / functions) is also a good idea. Also this program could potentially never end (or at least take long enough to where you would think it wouldn't end).

Comment: Hi @Andrew_CS, thanks for coming back. I meant drawNum(), and I updated that in my code.

Comment: Hm. It works for me on my end.

Comment: It looks like Logan guessed what the problem was and fixed it.

Comment: Note that `getNum()` generates a random number. This means that you should use it instead of `Math.random()` in your `bingoCard()` method.

Comment: The condition there is a bit different, as the numbers within the array for the first column are numbers 1 - 15, and they increment by 15 each column, to the max of five columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This my recommendation - Learn Object Oriented Programming immediately

I see you are using objects provided in the JDK, so why not learn to make your own?

Make two classes with the following methods (-) and members (+) (PS. This is not a formal way to document code)

```
BingoCard
    +list of numbers on card
    -reset() : gets new numbers for this card
    -test(BingoDrawer) : Tests to see if this card won on this drawing
    -toString() : returns a String representation of this card

BingoDrawer
    +list of numbers drawn
    -reset() : draws new numbers
    -hasNumber(int number) : tests if this number was drawn
    -toString() : returns a String representation of this drawing
```

One more suggestions

- Instead of keeping track of what you used, keep track of what you have not used, it will make things much easier because you can just choose stuff from that list randomly. Unlike your current action which is choosing (a logical number) from thin air and hoping (which causes issues) it is not a collision

If you follow my recommendation you can write code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BingoCard bc = new BingoCard();
    BingoDrawer bd = new BingoDrawer();
    while(thePlayerWantsToPlay()) { //function to be defined by you
        bc.reset();
        bd.reset();
        System.out.println(bc);
        System.out.println(bd);
        System.out.println(bc.test(bd));
    }
}
```

You can take it a step further and make a `BingoGame` class and do what I did in `main` there and just create an instance of `BingoGame` and call some `start` method on the object.

Answer (score 1):

For checking if you have the number in your board, read through the board in a similar manner as you do for the already_used numbers, except with the number the user just entered.

The conditions for the user to win should be checked after the board has another number guessed.
There are a few ways to do this, a simple one would be to iterate over every possible pattern that could win, checking to see if there are tokens there.

All of this would be in a loop, that goes a little like this:

```
Set up board via user entering numbers.
Start loop
    set either a timer to wait for, or wait for a keypress (so the game doesn't just play really fast)
    Get random number
    Possibly add to board
    Check if winner
    if winner, break the loop and do something else.
    Print the new board out.
(end of loop)
If they got here, that could mean they won!
Wait to exit
```

Comment: FYI - In Bingo the user doesn't guess numbers.

Comment: Well, the user has to do something... otherwise its not much of a game is it... (and I haven't played bingo in ages)

Comment: Generally the user would choose their board.

Comment: In this particular "game," the game is "played" by a random number generator that generates integers from 1 - 75.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write it out as pseudo-code and fill in the methods after that. It usually helps to work on these things in a top-down fashion. So, for bingo you might have:

```
board = generateBoard();
while (!bingoFound(board)) {
    number = drawNumber();
    board = stampNumbers(board, number);
}
```

If that makes sense, you can go a step deeper and define each method. For example, `bingoFound` might look like:

```
public boolean bingoFound(int[][] board) {
    boolean wasFound = bingoRowFound(board)
                    || bingoColFound(board)
                    || bingoDiagonalFound(board);
    return wasFound;
}
```

Again, I've defined everything in (mostly) pseudo-code. If this looks ok, you can move a step deeper. Let's define the `bingoRowFound` method.

```
public boolean bingoRowFound(int[][] board) {
    for (int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
        boolean rowIsABingo = true;
        for (int col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
            // We have to check that everything up until this point has
            // been marked off. I am using -1 to indicate that a spot has
            // been marked.
            rowIsABingo = rowIsABingo && board[row][col] == -1;
        }
        if (rowIsABingo) { return rowIsABingo; }
    }
    return false; // If we didn't find a bingo, return false.
}
```

Some of the methods (like `drawNumber`) will be *really* easy to implement. Others, like looking for a diagonal bingo might be a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Feb 12 2014 Update:

Retracted code, since this was a college course assignment, and I want to prevent people just copying the code. I almost got in trouble for being accused of sharing code (which is a nono in assignments) when another student lifted my code from my Github repo and sent it in as their own.

---

There were two classes, one main class and a class to hold my methods and constructors.

`BINGOFINAL.java` was my `main` class.

`Bingo_Card.java` held my `constructor` and `methods`.

If you want to run this, make sure you create a new project called BINGOFINAL, and put Bingo_Card.java into that same */src/ extension.

Comment: There is a lot of redundancy in this code. You should take the 6 lines of code that print "You Win" (and exits the program) into a function and instead call that function. Another option is to combine all of your if conditions using logical or `||`. For extra challenge (and readablility) I recommend you use loops to test for winning, not hard coding. Good job getting it to work though.

Comment: Also you could just `System.out.println("  B    I    N    G    O  ");` instead of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, that's right. I was actually quite limited to time. When you're rushed with time your mind tends to do silly things :P I re-wrote it after I went home and I am totally aware of those redundancies, haha. Afterwards, I also made a graphical user interface for this piece of code, with this being the result: http://puu.sh/4bOmS/593a78a87c.png I do have one issue - though. The conditions for Bingo is normally random digits from 1 - 15 per column (incremented). In my GUI, now it's switched to row. I might make a new post to fix that bug.